# How to replace only specific part of the string with condition under iMacros

Tags: javascript, automation, imacros

**I want to do the following help me making this script:**

```
if form text include = "ABC" (for example: "Whatever words ABC")
then delete the word "ABC" (so it become "Whatever words")

AND

if form text doesn't include = "ABC"
then add the word at the end "ABC (so it become "Whatever words ABC")
```

Please note: I dont want to touch the contained string only the part of it where it is `"ABC"` and or delete this part only.

I hope you can understand.

**I need this script to work under iMacros (web automation software)**

**SOLVED:** `SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.includes('ABC') ? '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace('ABC','') : '{{!EXTRACT}} ABC';")`

Comment: Guys I am really sorry for this I need this script to be worked in iMacros (a web autmation software) I hope you know about that, its uses javascript combined with its own script I am not sure what they call it but its a bit different. Please if you can tell me how to make this script work under that program that would be so helpful.

Comment: Solved: After some deep searching and trail and error i figured it out: SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.includes('ABC') ? '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace('ABC','') : '{{!EXTRACT}} ABC';")

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    var str = "Whatever words ABC";

    if (str.indexOf('ABC') !== -1)
      str.replace('ABC', '')
    else
      str+= ' ABC'
```

Comment: Thank you for this but do you any idea how can I make this script work in iMacros software?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str ="ABCDEFGHI"


if(str.indexOf("ABC") !== -1){
str.replace(/ABC/g,"")
}else{
str=str+"ABC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove a specific text and use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) to add text.

```js
var str = "Whatever words ABC";
var newStr = "";

if (str.indexOf("ABC") > -1) {
  newStr = str.replace(" ABC", "");
} else {
  newStr = str.concat(" ABC");
}

console.log(newStr);
```